# Computer Architecture and Organization MIPS language

Tags: mips

i have an assignment in mips and i'm having trouble writing it. I need to write a program that reads two strings then concatenates these two strings in a third string and prints the third string. I could do the concatenating part alone and the string reading alone but i can't figure out how to do them both in one program. Can anyone please help?

Here's the code, i found it online but it was for concatenating two strings without reading them  i tried to edit it so that it reads the two strings but it didn't work.

```
    .data        
    str1: .space 50

    str2: .space 50

    result: .space 100

     .text

    la $a0,result# get address of output

    li $v0,8

    la $a1,str1 # pass address of str1

    li $a1,100

    syscall

     li $v0,8

     la $a2,str2 # pass address of str2

     li $a2,100

     syscall

     jal conc

     # output the concatenated string

     la $a0,result

     li $v0,4

     syscall

    # BUG: no exit program

    li $v0,10

    syscall

   # conc -- concatenate strings char-by-char
   #
   # arguments:

   # a0 -- output pointer

   # a1 -- pointer to string to concatenate

   # a2 -- pointer to string to concatenate

    conc:

    lb $t1,0($a1) # get string char

    beqz $t1,conc_no1st # EOS? if yes, skip

    addi $a1,$a1,1 # advance 1st source pointer

    sb $t1,0($a0) # add to output

    addi $a0,$a0,1 # advance output pointer

    conc_no1st:

    lb $t2,0($a2) # add to output

    beqz $t2,conc_no2nd # EOS? if yes, skip

    addi $a2,$a2,1 # advance 2nd source pointer

    sb $t2,0($a0) # add to output


    addi $a0,$a0,1 # advance output pointer

    conc_no2nd:

    or $t1,$t1,$t2 # both chars EOS?

    bnez $t1,conc # no, loop

    sb $zero,0($a0) # store final EOS

    jr $ra
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your code, so it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: You say "i tried to edit it so that it reads the two strings but it didn't work" - does the code here include those edits or is there other changes that aren't shown?

Comment: yes they are shown i put , li $v0 8